# Why is recorded date not getting modified in Qualtrics embedded data API for response?

Tags: qualtrics

We are trying to modify certain fields of response of a survey through the embedded data API:

```
/API/v3/responses/{responseId}
```

However, although the embedded data fields are getting modified, the recorded date is not getting changed.

We tried changing the resetRecordedDate to either true or false but to no avail.